# Futuro ipotetico nel passato

Tags: subjunctive-mood, conditional-mood

Non riuscivo a pensare a un titolo migliore. In breve, sono indeciso fra le seguenti:

> Avrebbero potuto concedermi un'ora come una settimana, a seconda di quanto fossero stati generosi.
> Avrebbero potuto concedermi un'ora come una settimana, a seconda di quanto sarebbero stati generosi.

L'idea è che nel passato indicato dalla frase, non sappiamo ancora quanto saranno generosi. Quale delle due è corretta, e perché?

**Edit:** Siccome pare ci sia confusione sulla semantica intesa della frase, la seguente ne è una parafrasi. *Ieri, nel passato, non sapevo ancora quanto, nel futuro di quel passato, sarebbero stati generosi con me, e quindi sulla base di questa generosità, quanto tempo mi avrebbero concesso. (Oggi, nel presente, so che non sono stati generosi.)*

```
                                      PASSATO     PRESENTE
-----------------------------------------------|--------------->
   |                |                                       |
  ieri     generosi => tempo concesso                      oggi
```

Comment: Lo so che sembra una vigliaccata, ma io piuttosto che cacciarmi in un ginepraio così scriverei “...a seconda della loro generosità”, o qualche altro giro di parole.

Comment: No, lo capisco, ma ci sono delle ragioni. Primo, per principio: la cosa sta andando avanti da un po' e sento la necessità di chiarire la questione. Secondo, si tratta di una traduzione, quindi più è fedele all'originale e meglio è.

Comment: “...una traduzione, quindi più è fedele all'originale e meglio è”: non ti far sentire dai traduttologi, per cui la parola “fedele” è quasi impronunciabile; solo “letterale” è peggio. Comunque, se il testo originale era scorrevole e privo di complessità sintattiche di questo tipo, è più “fedele” tradurlo in un modo altrettanto scorrevole, senza subordinate che creano problemi anche a noi italiani.

Comment: Entrando nel merito, siamo sicuri che sia un “futuro nel passato”? A me l'ordine logico sembra: X è  più o meno generoso; X mi concede un'ora o più; oggi racconto il tutto. No?

Comment: (E mi scuso se il mio tono può suonare troppo tranchant: è una domanda molto interessante.)

Comment: In inglese si userebbe senza esitare “depending on how they would be generous” perché il condizionale semplice è sufficiente a collocare in rapporto alla principale; in italiano il condizionale rende il periodo molto poco scorrevole e il congiuntivo trapassato è raccapricciante. Meno orrido sarebbe il congiuntivo passato.

Comment: @DaG Lo so, mi spiace per il titolo. L'ordine logico che vorrei esprimere è: tempo (passato) della frase, X è generoso o meno, quasi immediatamente dopo X mi concede più o meno tempo come conseguenza logica, nel presente racconto tutto. Più precisamente: nel passato della frase non so se saranno generosi, mentre nel presente lo so per certo (e in effetti non lo sono stati).

Comment: @egreg In effetti l'originale è inglese e la subordinata usa proprio quella costruzione.

Comment: La seconda frase mi pare corretta e, personalmente, non la trovo ingarbugliata, anzi per me assolve bene lo scopo prefisso.

Answer (score 3):

Entrambe le frasi, indipendentemente dalla “correttezza” (che è sempre un concetto scivoloso), in italiano suonano piuttosto macchinose, a differenza – a quel che è emerso nei commenti – dell'originale inglese.

Quindi, se mi trovassi a rivedere un testo con una di quelle frasi, consiglierei caldamente di esprimere lo stesso concetto per via nominale anziché con una subordinata:

> Avrebbero potuto concedermi un'ora come una settimana, a seconda della loro generosità

e *proprio* perché è più “fedele” al testo una frase che suona liscia che una che, in ogni caso, attira su di sé l'attenzione del lettore il quale, per esempio, potrebbe a sua volta soffermarsi a valutarne la correttezza. Il dibattito qui mostra, quanto meno, che non è ovvio se lo sia o no.

Answer (score 1):

A mio parere, la seconda è decisamente quella corretta. Infatti, seguendo Serianni, *Italiano*, XI.395:

> Il condizionale (e precisamente, almeno oggi, il condizionale composto) rappresenta inoltre «lo strumento deputato per eccellenza» (BERTINETTO 1986:511) ad esprimere la nozione di posteriorità rispetto a un punto prospettico collocato nel passato.

Le altre alternative che Serianni offre per il futuro nel passato (imperfetto di *dovere*, imperfetto prospettivo e futuro retrospettivo) non sembrano applicabili in questo contesto, e sono comunque ben diverse dal congiuntivo trapassato.

Io capirei la prima frase come una lamentela: gli interlocutori non erano stati generosi (e il parlante lo sa), ma avrebbero potuto.

Comment: In effetti il mio caso sarebbe proprio quello di una lamentela, quasi nel senso di un'ipotesi irrealizzabile, tranne che non abbiamo un *se/allora*, ma solo un *a seconda di*. Il dubbio a questo punto era quello di affermare erroneamente, usando il congiuntivo, che il fatto di essere generosi o meno precede nel tempo il momento in cui si svolge l'azione della frase, dove ci resta solo da verificare le conseguenze su quanto ci concederanno. Comunque approfondirò sulla tua risposta, grazie.

Comment: Una precisazione: è corretto dire che il parlante non sapeva quanto sarebbero stati generosi; la lamentela è nel presente.

Comment: @giofrida Per me la differenza è con il congiuntivo trapassato le persone sono già state generose (o meno), mentre con il condizionale passato le persone non lo sono ancora state. Detto questo dovrei vedere il contesto per dire di più.

Comment: Infatti è lo stesso che ho pensato anch'io. Però considera anche questa frase: *Mi disse che se io fossi stata generosa con lui, allora lui avrebbe ricambiato.* Secondo me qui il congiuntivo è corretto e succede nel tempo il momento in cui *mi disse*. Riguardo il contesto: avevo cambiato un po' la frase perché fosse più chiara, ma direi che nel presente ci lamentiamo che una commissione non abbia voluto concederci del tempo per un progetto, determinandone il fallimento. La frase potrebbe continuare con: *Alla fine, non mi concessero nemmeno il tempo di sgombrare la scrivania.*

Comment: In effetti, forse è proprio questo il punto: generosi o meno, nel passato noi sappiamo per certo che verrà il momento in cui decideranno quanto tempo concederci. Forse questa certezza è il motivo per cui il condizionale è da preferirsi.

Comment: Come dicevo anche altrove, questa è giustamente la costruzione del “futuro nel passato”, ma la frase dell'OP in realtà esprime un “passato nel passato” (sono generosi o meno; poi concedono più o meno tempo; poi il narratore ci racconta il tutto).

Comment: @DaG Io avevo interpretato la frase diversamente: mi aspettavo che il narratore stesse aspettando (con ansia?) la decisione non ancora presa. Comunque, senza contesto, è difficile decidere.

Comment: Ah, capisco, @DenisNardin, ma allora ci sono addirittura quattro piani temporali: il narratore in attesa; la generosità del suo interlocutore (che è quella che è, prima, durante e dopo); la decisione dell'interlocutore; il narratore che narra. Che casino... :)

Comment: Insomma, se vogliamo proprio destrutturarla così allora in effetti sembra un casino, ma la verità è che stiamo semplicemente parlando di qualcosa che nel passato non era ancora successo. L'essere generosi e quanto concedere, più che in relazione temporale, sono in relazione logica.